# Xamarin #If Android not working

Tags: android, xamarin

I was having a lot of linking problem from an imported Android code and thus created a new Android Library project in which I imported most of the code from the other project.

But now I have a totally different problem: all of my "#If Android" statements now return false. I'm working with Xamarin and MonoAndroid.

Comment: Post your code so that users can look into your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created a new Android Library project, make sure you included the "Android" symbol in your new project.  It's in your project settings under "Compiler" and "Define Symbols" or something along those lines.

Comment: Currently in VS 2017: Right click project -> Properties -> Build -> "Conditional compilation symbols:"